# How to Match a password in Flask Peewee

Tags: python, flask

I create a user login function. In this i match a username and password . But in this only username is compared , Password comparison does not work. Help me how to compare both username and password.
Login function :-

```
@app.route('/loginpage', methods = ['GET' , 'POST' ] )
def loginpage():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['username']:
        user = User.select().where(User.username == request.form['username']).get()
        user.check_password(request.form['password'])
        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Custom Form :-

```
<form action=" " method="POST" class="form" >
    <dl>
      <dt>Username:</dt>
      <dd><input type="text" name="username"></dd>
      <dt>Password:</dt>
      <dd><input type="password" name="password"></dd>

      <dd><input type="submit" value="Login">
    </dl>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the error using this code in login function.

```
@app.route('/loginpage', methods = ['GET' , 'POST' ] )
def loginpage():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['username']:
        user = User.select().where(User.username == request.form['username']).get()
        if user.check_password(request.form['password']):
            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
        else:
            return 'invalid password'   

    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```